# share hooks across components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to understand how to share hooks state across components. But it doesn't seem to be sharing. Am I doing something wrong here?

Home.js

```
export default function Home() {
    
    const [search, setSearch]= useState('');
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Input search={search} handleChange={setSearch}  />
            <Products search={search} handleChange={setSearch} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Input.js

```
export default function Input({search, setSearch}) {
  
    

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      setSearch(e.target.value)
  }
  
    return (
    <div className='App'>

    <input 
    placeholder='search...' 
    value={search}
    onChange={handleChange}
    />


{search}
   

    </div>
  )
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState } = React;

/*export default*/ function Home() {
    
    const [search, setSearch]= useState('');
    
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Input search={search} handleChange={setSearch}  />
            <Products search={search} handleChange={setSearch} />
        </div>
    )
}

/*export default*/ function Input({search, setSearch}) {
  
    

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      setSearch(e.target.value)
  }
  
    return (
    <div className='App'>

    <input 
    placeholder='search...' 
    value={search}
    onChange={handleChange}
    />


{search}
   

    </div>
  )
}

const Products = ({search}) => {
    return <div>Product: {search}</div>;
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
.render(<Home />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: **It's a typo.** You've passed `setSearch` to `Input` as `handleChange`, but then you're trying to use it as `setSearch`. Change `<Input search={search} handleChange={setSearch} />` to `<Input search={search} setSearch={setSearch} />`.

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). *(Edit: I've done it for you, which showed me the problem above.)*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You pass `handleSearch` as prop in your `Home` component but `Input` is expecting `setSearch`, so just change this line in your `Home`

```
return (
  <div>
    <Input search={search} setSearch={setSearch}  />  // change here
    <Products search={search} handleChange={setSearch} />
  </div>
)
```